# How to resolve user undefined error on authjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, jwt, passport.js

creating web token using **passport LocalStrategy** and **passport-jwt**, but stuck on **user** undefined error, on auth.js ****401 Unauthorized**** (`if (!user) { return res.json(401, { error: 'message' });}`) 
how to resolve this issue,

**auth.js**

```
var express         = require('express');
var router          = express.Router();
var bodyParser      = require('body-parser')
var LocalStrategy   = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var jwt             = require('jsonwebtoken');
var passport        = require('passport');


/* User Model*/
var mongoose        = require('mongoose');
var User            = mongoose.model('User');


/* POST login. */
router.post('/login', function (req, res, next) {


passport.authenticate('local', {session: false}, (err, user, info) => {

if (err) { return next(err) }
if (!user) { return res.json(401, { error: 'message' });}

req.login(user, {session: false}, (err) => {
if (err) {
    res.send(err);
           }
           const token = jwt.sign(user, 'your_jwt_secret');
           return res.json({user, token});
        });
    })(req, res, next);
});


module.exports = router;
```

**passport.js**

```
var passport        = require('passport');

/* User Model*/
var mongoose        = require('mongoose');
var User            = mongoose.model('User');

var localStrategy   = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var passportJWT   = require("passport-jwt");
var JWTStrategy   = passportJWT.Strategy;
var ExtractJWT    = passportJWT.ExtractJwt;





passport.use(new localStrategy(
    function (email, password, cb) {
            return User.findOne({email, password})
           .then(user => {
                if (!user) {
       return cb(null, false, {message: 'Incorrect email or password.'});
                }

                return cb(null, user, {
                    message: 'Logged In Successfully'
                });
            })
            .catch(err => {
                return cb(err);
            });
    }
));



passport.use(new JWTStrategy({
        jwtFromRequest: ExtractJWT.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
        secretOrKey   : 'your_jwt_secret'
    },
    function (jwtPayload, cb) {

        return User.findById(jwtPayload.id)
            .then(user => {
                return cb(null, user);
            })
            .catch(err => {
                return cb(err);
            });
    }
));
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming user is an object:

```
if (user && Object.keys(user).length) { 
  return res.json(401, { error: 'message' });
}
```

Comment: Probably, it didn't find the user in your database or check if the inputs (email, password) are being successfully retrieved from the client or not.

Comment: how to pass req.body.email on passportjs ?